# Regarding the output_padding problem in nn.conv3d

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

```
    def __init__(
        self,
        in_channels,
        out_channels,
        kernel_size=(3, 3),
        stride=(1, 1),
        padding="same",
        dilation = [1,1],
        do_actnorm=True,        
        weight_std=0.05,
        groups = 1,
    ):
        super().__init__()

        if padding == "same":
            padding = compute_same_pad(kernel_size, stride)
        elif padding == "valid":
            padding = 0

        self.conv = nn.Conv3d(
            in_channels,
            out_channels,
            kernel_size,
            stride,
            padding,
            dilation,
            groups,
            bias=(not do_actnorm),
        )
```

I have this block of code. It is not working for 3D. The error says

```
expected output_padding to be a single integer value or a list of 2 values to 
match the convolution dimensions, but got output_padding=[0, 0, 0]
```

. It is only possible when convtranspose3d is being used. For 2d it's working fine. The dimesnions in 3d model I have was (B,C,H,W,D) i.e.; (1,1988,8,8,8) which I think is correctly applied.

I'm using pytorch version of 1.12.1

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem occurs because you are using 2-D tuples for kernel_size, stride, padding and dilation. Conv3d works in 3 dimensions (D, H, W), so that's why you didn't get an error for Conv2d with 2-D tuples.

To represent the problem I've used this Python code:

```py
import torch
from torch import nn

# create 5-D tensor
bs, c, d, h, w = 32, 3, 14, 64, 64
inp = torch.ones((bs, c, d, h, w))
```

So I've created a convolution with your default parameters:

```py
bad_conv = nn.Conv3d(
    in_channels=3,
    out_channels=16,
    kernel_size=(3, 3),
    stride=(1, 1),
    padding=(0, 0),
    dilation=(1, 1),
    groups=1,
    bias=False,
)

bad_out = bad_conv(inp)
print(bad_out.shape)
```

And I've got the same error:

```py
RuntimeError: expected output_padding to be a single integer value or a list
of 2 values to match the convolution dimensions, but got output_padding=[0, 0, 0]
```

You should use 3-D tuples, something like this:

```py
good_conv = nn.Conv3d(
    in_channels=3,
    out_channels=16,
    kernel_size=(3, 3, 3),
    stride=(1, 1, 1),
    padding=(0, 0, 0),
    dilation=(1, 1, 1),
    groups=1,
    bias=False,
)

good_out = good_conv(inp)
print(good_out.shape)
```

Output:

```py
torch.Size([32, 16, 12, 62, 62])
```